# XCopy failing during build but not from command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build-process, xcopy

I have a console program that outputs its exe & dlls to a specified directory.

As a post build event I am trying to copy everything in that directory to another directory.

My xcopy command works from command prompt but fails in VS2010? How can this be?

I am testing it by going to the project folder and executing the following in command prompt. (it is the output from VS2010)

In my post-build event:

```
xcopy "$(OutDir)*.*" "$(TargetDir)..\..\Foo\Bar\" /s /y /i
```

From command prompt I am executing the following which works.

```
xcopy "..\..\..\..\MyDir\baz\zip\*.*" "c:\1\2\3\MyDir\baz\zip\..\..\Foo\Bar\" /s /y /i
```

Sorry about the directory names.

End result should be two directories with the same files in them:

```
c:\1\2\3\MyDir\baz\zip
c:\1\2\3\MyDir\foo\bar
```

The target path is relative to the output directory.

When its executed as part of the build it gives an exit code 4

> Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk
>   space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the
>   command line.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You might to replace `xcopy` with a `xcopy.bat` that you write which logs parameters and results to see whats going on

Comment: out of curiosity, if you replace the relative paths with absolute paths, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Got it,

I changed the xcopy command in my post build event to:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.*" "$(TargetDir)..\..\Foo\Bar\" /s /y /i
```

The executed result being:

```
xcopy "c:\1\2\3\MyDir\baz\zip\*.*" "c:\1\2\3\MyDir\baz\zip\..\..\Foo\Bar\" /s /y /i
```

Which VS2010 much preferred, I guess you can't use a relative path without a base path.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don'y call batch file which will run xcopy for required files source to destination?

```
call "$(SolutionDir)scripts\copyifnewer.bat"
```

With copyifnewer.bat looking like this:

```
IF NOT EXIST <destination> md <destination>
XCOPY /Y <file> <destination>
```